# Filter string based on ending convention

Tags: c#

I got strings which i want to take only those of them which have ending on for instance:

```
-id-3     (e.g somother33-id-3)
-id-203   (e.g som78estringetc-id-203)
-id-54    (e.g fwefwefwefw-id-3)
```

but sometimes i am retreiving strings which looks like this one i dont want to get

```
som78estringetc-id-203:someotherstring3-1
```

i am intrested only those string which ends by -id-somedigit
So string which i would like to get are those ending by convention:

```
somestring-id-digit
```

Could anyone help me how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Using regex you can simply do:

```
-id-[0-9]*$
```

If you want to exclude your other item you could try:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]*-id-[0-9]*$
```

Comment: this case i will only take those strings ending by -id-digit for sure? And how i can comapre it in code to specific string?

Comment: @StackUser: True, I've updated to reflect your double item. I don't understand your 2nd question

Answer (score 0):

> try to use regex.

```
Regex.IsMatch("asdfadid-13234234", @"\w*-Id-[0-9]*$\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

this case best would be `@"\w*-Id-[0-9]*$\b"` right?